# Блокирование приложения

Tags: java, android, google-play

Могут ли заблокировать приложение, если я использую иконки VK, Facebook, GMail и прочие иконки соц сетей для того, чтобы пользователь смог перейти на страницу разработчика?

Comment: не заблокируют, не переживайте

Answer (score 5):

Нет, за публикацию ссылок разработчика в соц. сетях приложение не блокируют, поэтому не беспокойтесь.

Ну а вообще, *Google* подготовил довольно-таки хорошую справку, где четко описаны [правила публикации приложений](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) на русском языке.